# JS Click event doesn't work

Tags: javascript

The code:

```
document.getElementById("theid").onfocus=function fone(){
    document.onkeypress = function(myEvent) {
        var code = myEvent.which;
        if ((code === 13) || (code === 32)) {
            document.querySelector('.someclass').click();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't get what is wrong with my code...

I'm trying to call the `click()` when Enter or Space buttons are used while the element in focus.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I just got too much of learning the code for today, I guess. The case wasn't the click event. The code is correct.

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. Can you put this in context with the HTML this is supposed to work on?

Comment: What errors do you see in the console?

Comment: You are adding a keypress handler to your document object _only when_ element "theid" gets focus.  There is no handler until that element is focused. In addition, you are adding _another_ keypress handler _every time_ the element gets focus.

Comment: Stephen P, Is that a bad thing? I feel like you're describing what am I actually trying to do :)

Comment: @franeous - adding the handler every time focus is gained **_is_** a bad thing; you can end up with 10 (or 100) handlers attached that all do the same thing.  If you only want the keypress handler for 13/32 to be in effect when `"theid"` is focused you can either attach the handler to `document` once and check where the current focus is, or _detach_ the handler on _blur_. Now you attach the handler to document when you get focus, and never detach it. If the handler is always going to be there just attach it once, on document ready, and if only there for focus then detach it on blur.

Comment: Took me a while to get you, because this all kinda new to me. But I think I got you. In your way I will basically follow the DRY-code(I know what it is!:) ) rule, am I? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use JQuery to get this. Please see the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ko842xbp/

```
document.getElementById("theid").onfocus=function fone(){
    document.onkeypress = function(myEvent) {

        var code = myEvent.which;
        if ((code === 13) || (code === 32)) {

           $('.someclass').click();
        }
    }
}

 $('.someclass').click(function(){

 alert(".someclass was clicked")

 });
```

Comment: Instead of `$('.someclass').click();` use `document.querySelector('.someclass').click();` and it will work as well... Sorry, I just got too of learning the code for today, I guess. The case wasn't the click event.